# Everytime I restart my laptop, all plugins in eclipse getting deleted

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-neon

I am using Neon 3 in Macbook Pro. Everytime i restart my laptop, all the installed plugins are getting deleted on opening Eclipse again. But a pop up to installed again. So, everytime I restart the laptop, I install literally all the plugins. This is happening for the past couple of weeks. Any suggestions how to stop this from happening.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is outdated.